# Mongo shell - update causes TypeError: object is not a function at Mongo.getDB (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
var config = {
  marketingDB: 'localhost:27017/marketing',
  feedbackDB: 'localhost:27017/feedback',
  teleporterDB: 'localhost:27017/teleporter',
  batchSz: 1000
};

var DB = {
  marketingDB: connect(config.marketingDB),
  feedbackDB: connect(config.feedbackDB),
  teleporterDB: connect(config.teleporterDB)
};

function Datasegment() {
  var db = DB.teleporterDB;
  var datasegmentCollectionObjects = {};

  function init() {
    var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames();
    for (var i in collectionNames) {
      var datasegmentName = collectionNames[i];
      datasegmentCollectionObjects[datasegmentName] = db[datasegmentName]
    }
  };

  this.getCollection = function(dataSegmentName) {
    return datasegmentCollectionObjects[dataSegmentName];
  };

  init();
};

function Template() {
  var db = DB.marketingDB;

  this.findAllTemplateDataSnapshotMap = function() {
    var results = {};
    db.template.find().forEach(
      function(rec){
        if(rec.data_snapshot_id) {
          results[rec._id] = rec.data_snapshot_id;
        }
      });

    return results;
  };
}

function Runbook() {
  var db = DB.feedbackDB;
  var datasegment = new Datasegment();
  var template = new Template();

  this.merge = function() {
    var templateIdDatasegmentNameMap = template.findAllTemplateDataSnapshotMap();
    printjson(templateIdDatasegmentNameMap);
    var jobDataSegmentMapping = getJobIdDataSegmentMapping(templateIdDatasegmentNameMap);
    printjson(jobDataSegmentMapping);
    mergeAllTeleporterDataToRunbook(jobDataSegmentMapping);
  };

  function getRunbookCollection(jobId) {
    return db[jobId];
  }

  function getRunbookCollectionWrite(jobId) {
    return writeDB[jobId];
  }

  function getRequestRowIndexInDataSegment(channel, requestId) {
        var lastPos = requestId.lastIndexOf("_");
        var idx = 0;

        if (channel == 'push') {
            var usualReqId = requestId.substring(lastPos + 1, requestId.length - 1);
            var lastToLastPos = usualReqId.lastIndexOf("_");
            idx = usualReqId.substring(lastToLastPos + 1, requestId.length - 1);
        } else {
            idx = requestId.substring(lastPos + 1, requestId.length - 1);
        }
        return idx;
  }

  function getRequestRowInDataSegment(datasegmentCollection, index) {
        return datasegmentCollection.find().skip(index).limit(1).next()
  }

  function mergeTeleporterDataToRunbook(jobId, runbookCollection, datasegmentCollection ) {
        if (!runbookCollection || !datasegmentCollection) {
          return; // fall back to do nothing
        }

        try {
        var sz = runbookCollection.find().count();
        var offset = 0;

        while (offset <= sz) {
          var batchData = [];
          runbookCollection.find().skip(offset).limit(config.batchSz).forEach(function(ref) {
            if (ref.user_id) {
                // this is already populated. No need
                throw 100;
            }

            var index = getRequestRowIndexInDataSegment(ref.channel, ref.request_id);
            var datasegmentRow = getRequestRowInDataSegment(datasegmentCollection, index);
            var info = {};
            if (datasegmentRow.user_id) {
              info['user_id'] = datasegmentRow.user_id;
            }

            if(ref.channel === 'sms') {
              if (datasegmentRow.phone) {
                info['phone'] = datasegmentRow.phone;
              }
            }

            if(ref.channel === 'email') {
              if (datasegmentRow.email) {
                info['email'] = datasegmentRow.email;
              }
            }

            //runbookCollection.update({request_id : ref.request_id}, { $set : info });
            batchData.push({request_id: ref.request_id, info: info});
          }
          );

          for (var i in batchData) {
            var ref = batchData[i];
            // this is the line with error
            runbookCollection.update({request_id : ref.request_id}, { $set : ref.info });
          }
          offset = offset + batchData.length;
          batchData = [];
        }
        } catch (err) {
            if (err !== 100) throw err;
        }

        printjson("Done with " + jobId);
  }


  function mergeAllTeleporterDataToRunbook(jobDataSegmentMapping) {
    //printjson(jobDataSegmentMapping);
    for (var jobId in jobDataSegmentMapping) {
      var dataSegmentName = jobDataSegmentMapping[jobId];
      var runbookCollection = getRunbookCollection(jobId);
      var datasegmentCollection = datasegment.getCollection(dataSegmentName);
      mergeTeleporterDataToRunbook(jobId, runbookCollection,
                  datasegmentCollection);
    }
  }

  function getJobIdDataSegmentMapping(templateIdDatasegmentMap){
    var  jobDataSegmentMap = {};
    for(var i in templateIdDatasegmentMap) {
      db.dispatcher_jobs.find({templateId : i}).forEach(function(rec){
        jobDataSegmentMap[rec.jobId] = templateIdDatasegmentMap[i];
      });
    }

    return jobDataSegmentMap;
  }
}

new Runbook().merge();
```

I am getting error in the update call. In this case mongo is setup as a replication cluster. I have another DB for which this has to work is a sharded one. Also, in that env I will be having different IPs for the 3 DBs.

The script is executed as `mongo script_name`

```
2015-11-23T20:39:12.674+0530 E QUERY    TypeError: object is not a function
    at Mongo.getDB (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:41:12)
    at Mongo.hasWriteCommands (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:204:29)
    at Mongo.writeMode (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:244:15)
    at DBCollection.update (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:443:26)
    at mergeTeleporterDataToRunbook (copy_user_info.mongo:154:31)
    at mergeAllTeleporterDataToRunbook (copy_user_info.mongo:173:7)
    at Runbook.merge (copy_user_info.mongo:66:5)
    at copy_user_info.mongo:190:15 at copy_user_info.mongo:160
failed to load: copy_user_info.mongo
```

Comment: if you run `console.log` on `ref.info` before the `runbookCollection.update...` what's the value?

Comment: `{ "email" : "someemail.l@gmail.com" }` This is what is expected also.

Comment: Your declaration of `DB` on line 10 is overriding the global `DB` variable, which leads to the TypeError (and will cause other issues in various shell methods). To avoid the problem, rename `DB` to something like `myDBs` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a work-around than a solution.
I went through Mongo's shell JS code, but could not find anything significant. But with trial and error I realized that the problem is with the way I am connecting different DBs from the same shell.

Here is what all I tried -
A single update without any other DB connection works fine (nn find call).
You add another DB connect and the update starts failing.

In my case I worked around this problem by splitting the read and write parts of the script and stitching them together with a python script (ugly). But everyone has deadlines to meet.

I have filed https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21664 for this issue.